# Php contact form with multiable radio buttons

Tags: php, html, css

I'm quite new to php and I am trying to code a contact form/questionnaire

I need the form to pull through the results of the radio button for example

EmployeeName: Ian Matthews
Mark: ( what ever radio button they click )
Comments: What ever comments they leave in the text box.

but if other names are filled in, then create a new line with the above details

EmployeeName: Ian Matthews
Mark: ( what ever radio button they click )
Comments: What ever comments they leave in the text box.

EmployeeName: Ciara Maguire
Mark: ( what ever radio button they click )
Comments: What ever comments they leave in the text box.

I am trying to use "foreach" but don't think I am using it correctly

Hope someone can help

Thanks

currently I have this code

```html
<?php

$EmailFrom = "";
$EmailTo = "";
$Subject = "Questionnaire";

$EmpName = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['EmployeeName']));
$Radio = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Radio']));
$Comment = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Com']));


foreach ($_POST ['Radio'] as $value) {
    $Body = "$EmpName, $Radio, $Comment\n";
  }


$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");


if ($success){
  print "top work";
}
else{
  print "you have a error";
}

?>
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="10" colspan="7"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <h4>Excellent</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Very Good</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Good</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Satisfactory</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Poor</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>N/A</h4>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30">
      <label>Ian Matthews
        <input type="hidden" name="EmployeeName" value="Ian Matthews" />
      </label>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="10-Excellent" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="7-VeryGood" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="4-Good" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="0-Satisfactory" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="-5-Poor" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="N/A" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30">
      <label class="colourGrey">Comments:</label>
    </td>
    <td colspan="6" align="center">
      <input class="teamCom" type="text" name="Com" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10" colspan="7"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" class="BorderLine"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10" colspan="7"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <h4>Excellent</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Very Good</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Good</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Satisfactory</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Poor</h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>N/A</h4>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30">
      <label>Ciara Maguire
        <input type="hidden" name="EmployeeName" value="Ciara Maguire" />
      </label>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="10-Excellent" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="7-VeryGood" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="4-Good" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="0-Satisfactory" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="-5-Poor" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="N/A" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30">
      <label class="colourGrey">Comments:</label>
    </td>
    <td colspan="6" align="center">
      <input class="teamCom" type="text" name="Com" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10" colspan="7"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" class="BorderLine"></td>
  </tr>
  
  </table>
```

Comment: All your HTML code is for the same form? Or each employee has his own form?

Comment: Hi, it is all on the same form so it will be submitted all at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First at all, you are using the same input names for both employees. You have to set different names:

```
<input type="hidden" name="EmployeeName1" value="Ian Matthews" />
<input type="hidden" name="EmployeeName2" value="Ciara Maguire" />
```

And this with all inputs (Com1 and Com2, radio1 and radio2,..)

In your php file, you have to do something like

```
$Body = "";
$numEmployees = 2; // or the number you put
// Each iteration per employee, accesing to his form data
for ($i=1; $i<=$numEmployees; $i++)
{
  $EmpName = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['EmployeeName' .$i]));
  $Comment = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Com' .$i]));
  $Radio = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['radio' .$i]));
  $Body .= "$EmpName, $Radio, $Comment\n";  // Note the dot in ".="
}
```

and then

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");
```

Of course, you have emailto and emailfrom empty, but I supose that you fill them in your final version.
I don't execute this version, but I hope can help you to understand your mistake.

Comment: I forgot explain why your foreach is wrong. You don't concatenate the var Body, so in each iteration it was been replacing. You are setting always with the same var Employee, Com and Radio. And finally, you are iterating with $value, but you use $Radio. For example, try to understand this code "$i = [1,4,5]; foreach ($i as $temp) { echo $temp;}"

Comment: Hi This worked great thanks, something i should of said was that if a radio or com isn't selected/empty i don't want it to display anything, so skip a name, id this possible?

Comment: Probably you want something like this. Inside the "for", enclose $Body with this condition "if ($Radio != "" || $Comment != "") { $Body=.... }". I meant, if $Radio or $Comment are different of empty string, assign the value to $Body.

Comment: so like this  $Body .= "$EmpName, $Radio, $Comment\n";  // Note the dot in ".="
  if ($Radio != "" || $Comment != "") { 
   $Body .= "";
   }

Comment: No, perhaps I didn't explain well. You have to change this line: `$Body .= "$EmpName, $Radio, $Comment\n";` for this : `if ($Radio != "" || $Comment != "") { $Body .= "$EmpName, $Radio, $Comment\n"; } ` because if you have a value in Radio or Comment, you want to add the name to $Body. If the condition is not true, you will not add anything to Body in **that** iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['Radio']` contains a single value, whereas you want to send through multiple values. For that, the best way would be to assign the inputs to an array, as such:

```
<input name="Radio[]" value="Lorem" />
<input name="Radio[]" value="ipsum" />
<input name="Radio[]" value="dolor" />
<input name="Radio[]" value="sit" />
<input name="Radio[]" value="amet" />
```

Then you can retrieve the results by accessing them as an array:

```
$_POST['Radio'][0] == 'Lorem'
$_POST['Radio'][4] == 'amet'
```

Finally, you are overwriting the assignment to $Body each time in your loop. Instead of `$Body = "$EmpName, $Radio, $Comment\n";`, you'll want `$Body .= "$EmpName, $Radio, $Comment\n";`. Note the dot before the equals. That appends to a variable rather than overwrites it.

Assuming that you only have one employee submitting one comment in addition to the many radio buttons responses per POST, you could then use something like:

```
foreach ($_POST ['Radio'] as $value) {
    $Body .= "$EmpName, $value, $Comment\n";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code like this -

```
        <form method="post" >

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="10" colspan="7"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <h4>Excellent</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Very Good</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Good</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Satisfactory</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Poor</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>N/A</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30">
          <label>Ian Matthews
            <input type="hidden" name="EmployeeName1" value="Ian Matthews" />
          </label>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name="Radio1" value="10-Excellent" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name="Radio1" value="7-VeryGood" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name="Radio1" value="4-Good" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name="Radio1" value="0-Satisfactory" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name="Radio1" value="-5-Poor" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name="Radio1" value="N/A" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30">
          <label class="colourGrey">Comments:</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="6" align="center">
          <input class="teamCom" type="text" name="Com1" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="10" colspan="7"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="7" class="BorderLine"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="10" colspan="7"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <h4>Excellent</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Very Good</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Good</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Satisfactory</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Poor</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>N/A</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30">
          <label>Ciara Maguire
            <input type="hidden" name="EmployeeName2" value="Ciara Maguire" />
          </label>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name="Radio2" value="10-Excellent" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name="Radio2" value="7-VeryGood" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name="Radio2" value="4-Good" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name="Radio2" value="0-Satisfactory" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name="Radio2" value="-5-Poor" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="radio" name="Radio2" value="N/A" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30">
          <label class="colourGrey">Comments:</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="6" align="center">
          <input class="teamCom" type="text" name="Com2" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="10" colspan="7"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="7" class="BorderLine"></td>
      </tr>

      </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Feedback" />

            </form>


     <?php

     if(isset($_POST)) {

    $EmailFrom = "";
    $EmailTo = "";
    $Subject = "Questionnaire";

    $Body = "";

    $noParaPerEmployee = 3;
    $n = 0;

    foreach ($_POST as $key=> $value) {
        //echo "$key => $value <br/>";
        //$Body .= "$EmpName, $Radio, $Comment\n";
        $Body .= "$value , ";
        $n++;
        if($n===3) {
            $Body = substr($Body,0, -2); // get rid of last comma..
            $Body .= "\n";
            $n = 0;
        }

      }

    //echo "$Body <br/>\n";
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");


    if ($success){
      print "top work";
    }
    else{
      print "you have a error";
    }

     }

    ?>
```